# How to access to fetched data from mongodb in erlang?

Tags: mongodb, erlang

I use [mongodb-erlang](https://github.com/mongodb/mongodb-erlang) driver for mongo db access in erlang. Some of my command execution:

```
34> {ok, Conn} = mongo:connect({localhost, 27017}).                                                          
{ok,{connection,{"localhost",27017},
                <0.89.0>,false,infinity}}

35> {ok, Data} = mongo:do(safe, master, Conn, homeweb, fun() -> mongo:find_one(user, {apartmentId, 1}) end).
{ok,{{'_id',{<<79,180,252,18,220,119,245,66,215,79,71,61>>},
            apartmentId,1.0,email,<<"e@mail.com">>,password,
            <<"efe6398127928f1b2e9ef3207fb82663">>}}}
```

Data is a tuple.

For example in php array is returned from find request and I can get `id` with code like this: `$id = $result['_id'];`.

The question is: how to access to fetched from db data in Erlang?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By [pattern matching](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/patterns.html). In this case, "Data" holds the result, so you might do something like:

```
1> {{'_id', {Id}, apartmentId, ApartmentId, email, Email, password, Password}} = Data.
{{'_id',{<<79,180,252,18,220,119,245,66,215,79,71,61>>},
        apartmentId,1.0,email,<<"e@mail.com">>,password,
        <<"efe6398127928f1b2e9ef3207fb82663">>}}
```

The words that start with an upper case will hold the values, so for example, you can print them:

```
2> ApartmentId.
1.0
3> Email.
<<"e@mail.com">>
4> Password.
<<"efe6398127928f1b2e9ef3207fb82663">>
5> Id.
<<79,180,252,18,220,119,245,66,215,79,71,61>>
```

EDIT: You are actually doing pattern matching when you run your query. Notice the **{ok, Data} =** on the left side of the = operator. This is effectively matching that the result is a tuple in the form {ok, Data} *and* since Data is unbound up to that point, it is assigned to the query result.

EDIT2: Since Data in this case is a bson(), you can refer to the erlang bson module (used as a dependency of the mongodb erlang driver): http://api.mongodb.org/erlang/bson/. There are specific functions you can use in this case, like bson:lookup/2 and bson:fields/1, passing as a parameter the bson() document (the result from mongodb:find_one/2)

Comment: Ok, what's happened if sequence on right side will be changed?

Comment: Pattern matching allows an assertion and an assignment at the same time. So if on the left side there's an unbound variable, it will be assigned to the value on the right side. If you have a literal, or an already bound variable, and then left side is not equal to the right side, then you will get a "no match of right hand side value" error. See: http://learnyousomeerlang.com/syntax-in-functions#pattern-matching

Comment: My comment was not about pattern matching. I meant that if I add some field in db it breaks my code, does not it?

Comment: @rdo In this particular case, you are retrieving all the fields. Adding a field will change the right side of the = operator, so in this sense this has to do with pattern matching. You can query by only the fields you need by using mongo:find_one/3 (the 3rd argument is the projector, the fields you need). In this way, you are sure you will always get the tuple you are looking for.

Comment: @rdo Just updated the question to include a reference to bson(), which may be nearer to your needs :)